# Unexpected token: operator (>) from UglifyJs

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, vue-loader, babel-loader

I have 2 Vue-Cli webpack projects (ClientApp and Lib).
Lib is my components library (shared with other projects)

#### Problem

When I build my project ClientApp `npm run build`, I have the following error:

```
ERROR in static/js/app.d08a24ce0e8d0438ce68.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: operator (>) [C:/.../Lib/src/tools/escape-key.js:3,0][static/js/app.d08a24ce0e8d0438ce68.js:17468,38]
```

#### Questions

It seems like the error comes from an arrow function in the file `escape-key.js`.
This is ES6 syntax and UglifyJS can't parse this.
Shouldn't Babel go first, before Uglify?
Note that is works well with `*.vue` files.

#### Project structure

```
ClientApp
   | - build
   | - config
   | - src
       | - App.Vue // import EscapeKey from '~lib/tools/escape-key';



Lib
  | -src
     | - tools
         | - escape-key.js
```

#### ClientApp's webpack.base.conf.js file

Note there is an alias to Lib.

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      '@': resolve('src'),
      '~lib': path.join(__dirname, '../../lib/src'),
    }
  },
```

Please feel free to ask for more details if required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After changing my babel-loader config, it worked.

#### Babel-loader config

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  include: [path.join(__dirname, '../../Lib/src'), resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
}
```

Comment: The webpack simple repository works perfectly fine: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple/blob/master/template/webpack.config.js So this might work for you, but this is not really the answer people are probably looking for. I am running into the same problem so I will try to figure out what is going on here.

Answer (score 11):

Add

```
"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "v1.0.0-beta.1",
```

to your dev dependencies and update your `webpack.config.js` file to use this version explicitly:

```
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new UglifyJSPlugin()
  ]
}
```

uglifyjs-webpack-plugin latest stable release (v0.4.6) uses older version of `uglify-js` instead of `uglify-es` that is capable of transpiling ES6. This dependency was updated in 1.0.0-beta.1 release.

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.1

Comment: There is 1.0.0 version released, so you can use that one as well.

Comment: You're my hero bro. I use Webpack 3 + Node 10.13 for anyone want to know

Answer (score 5):

The version of uglify that you are using probably doesn't support ES6.

https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/tree/harmony is the es6 version as of now

if you want to use the webpack [plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin), make sure to pay attention to the install section regarding es6

> **Important!** The plugin has a peer dependency to uglify-js, so in order to use the plugin, also uglify-js has to be installed. The
>   currently (2017/1/25) available uglify-js npm packages; however, do
>   not support minification of ES6 code. In order to support ES6, an
>   ES6-capable, a.k.a. *harmony*, version of UglifyJS has to be provided.
>
> If your minification target is ES6:
>
> `yarn add git://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#harmony-v2.8.22 --dev`

Comment: I have Babel running before Uglify to transpile es6 to es5. Babel did not transpiled some files because those files were not in include property of Babel-Loader

Answer (score 5):

This solved the problem for me.
I installed `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin`

```
npm install uglifyjs-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

Then added this to my `webpack.config`

```
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new UglifyJSPlugin()
  ]
}
```