# Webpack UglifyJS running into unexpected token

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-2

I am trying to set up a development boilerplate which can also easily push a Vue.js project to NPM.

I am running into  a problem with my `webpack.prod.js` file, the error is:

```
ERROR in build.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: operator (>)
```

The code to uglify is:

```
// minify with dead-code elimination
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    compress: {
        warnings: false
    }
})
```

This is my project and the exact file where it seems to go wrong:

https://github.com/stephan-v/vue-inline-svg/blob/master/webpack/webpack.prod.js

The project uses Babel to transpile to ES6 and Webpack to compile to UMD format when I run `npm run production`. This command uses the `webpack.prod.js` configuration.

I am probably not seeing something that could be fixed easily but I have no clue what is going wrong here.

Comment: seems can load file, and is the html of 404

Comment: Without the `UglifyJsPlugin` everything works fine. I have not actually tested the UMD file by importing it but it compiles fine without the plugin, so that is not the issue.

Comment: Similar answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43888474/unexpected-token-operator-from-uglifyjs

Comment: I've added the exact same `.babelrc` file from the `webpack-simple` repo of `vue.js` it works perfectly fine now. I will check out what it does exactly though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `.babelrc` file from the [webpack simple](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple/tree/master/template) repository fixed my issue. I am not sure what is going on here though:

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["env", { "modules": false }]
    ]
}
```

To my knowledge the `.babelrc` contains the plugins and options that tells babel how to transpile my code.

I revied what the `modules` option exactly is:

https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/#optionsmodules

It said the following:

> "amd" | "umd" | "systemjs" | "commonjs" | false, defaults to
>   "commonjs".
>
> Enable transformation of ES6 module syntax to another module type.
>
> Setting this to false will not transform modules.

Because I want my package to be available to all users and my `webpack` production configuration uses:

```
libraryTarget: 'umd'
```

To compile my code to `umd` formatting, will this not conflict with `"modules": false` though?

I am also used to seeing a `es2015` preset in the `.babelrc` file. This is nowhere to be found. Is this the default now?

It seems the `es2015` option has been entirely removed:

https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/commit/424cd3f6d101ffeb57f48bca55d7951b35af60e0

From what I've read so far it is because Webpack **2** already knows how to work with ES6 modules natively therefore the `"modules": false` disables and prevents babel from transpiling as well.

Feel free to leave a comment and correct me on any of this. I am saving this for future reference and for others to see who might also stumble into this.